# adding web app as a library to another web project

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a web application, basically the rest api built on struts framework. Whie building the code, it can create .war file as well and can be run on tomcat server.Now, I have another web application project implementing logging and other security  features. Is it possible to add the prior web application as a library to the latter web application so that i can implement some security featues to my rest-api's ?

In other words, I simply like to add web app (.war) file as library to another web project. Is it possible ? if possible, how ??

Comment: It seems strange that there would be a web application which only has logging and security, but nothing else.  In any case, I think you should be including your other project most likely as a JAR dependency in your current project.

Comment: If so, how can we convert .war into .jar. Just changing the suffix won't fix the problem.Is there any other way to help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a maven project, open pom.xml file. Change the packaging to jar. For that add this inside your  tag to convert it as jar.

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

If it is not a maven project, you can convert it to a maven project and follow the above steps and continue with your development.

**To add the jar file to the new project**
Inside the new project's pom.xml, add the jar as a dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.groupName</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraryName</artifactId>
        <version>versionNumber</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Please Note: The new project must be a maven project to do so.